Getting XML Value With PowerShell
I have an XML file formatted as:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configure class="some text">
  <!-- Eliminate Old / Insecure / Anonymous Ciphers -->
  <Call name="callname">
    <Arg>
      <Array type="String">
        <Item>.*NULL.*</Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
  <!-- Eliminate Insecure Protocols -->
  <Call name="addExcludeProtocols">
    <Arg>
      <Array type="java.lang.String">
        <Item>ITEM</Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
  <Set name="KeyStorePath">D:\Folder\Keystore.keystore</Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword">Password</Set>
</Configure>

My goal is to turn the KeyStorePath value (D:\Folder\Keystore.keystore) as a variable.  I have my path as
[xml]$TestPath = gc XML.xml
My thought was to run:
$TestPath.Configure.Set | Where-Object name -EQ 'KeyStorePath'
But this returns no results.  I would expect if I ran:
$TestPath.Configure.Set.Name
It would return KeyStorePath and KeyStorePassword, but it's only returning Set.  I attempted to run:
$TestPath.Configure.Set.Name.Set
And that returns nothing...  As always, I'm sure it's something obvious and I just need an extra set of eyes to tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Seems like you're after $xml.SelectSingleNode("//*[@name='KeyStorePath']").InnerText ?

$TestPath.Configure.Set | Where-Object name -EQ 'KeyStorePath' | ForEach-Object InnerText is fine too, that should be working properly. Are you certain that's returning no results?

Curious, someone else asked about the exact same last week :)

@SantiagoSquarzon those both worked, thank you!

@MathiasR.Jessen HA!  That is most likely my coworker.  We install software and I've attempted to automate most of my installs via PowerShell.  I have shared my scripts with him.  We had a new version and this particular part was altered by our developers in the latest release, so the script broke.  I was on vacation last week and he is on vacation this week, so we haven't actually talked to each other about this and I had no idea he was trying to crack the code already.

Note that there's a subtle, but important difference between these two very similar questions: only the linked one has a <!DOCTYPE> declaration with the same name as the document element, Configure.
As a result, $xmlDoc.Configure returns an array and  $xmlDoc.Configure.Set does not work as intended, but a simple workaround is to use $xmlDoc.DocumentElement.Set instead; see this answer to the linked question for details.

Thanks @mklement0, it actually is the same XML file, I just deleted a lot of stuff to try to hide any evidence of where the file may have come from.  So the solutions from both work.
